# MVC5 EF6 How to add confirmation screen with additional authentication before submitting data

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

Developing a new MVC5 project. I have my scaffolding in place for CRUD functionality but there is a requirement that when data is inserted or updated, an e-signature is required. Before data can be submitted to the database the user must be presented with a page asking them to enter their username and password again to confirm the data. If the username and password entered is valid and the username matches the currently signed in user, then the original data entered can be saved to its table (for example Member) and the e-signature information is saved to a separate table (ESignature). I'd appreciate any help on the best way to go about this - a view model combining Member and ESignature, or a reuse of the LoginViewModel from the Account controller to check the authentication, or an alternative approach? I need something that I can use across half a dozen controllers where e-signatures are required.

Answer (score 0):

Alright maybe my approach is not the best but I will attempt.

My solution would be to create a `CustomAttribute`: `AuthorizeAttribute` and decorate all the actions which require Esignature. In your CustomAttribute implementation you will redirect to a controller action exactly similar to Login but with slight modification.

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

            var url = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;
            var query = url.Query;
            if (query.Contains("g="))
            {
                var code = query.Split(new String[] { "g=" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                //You can create time sensistive token and validate it.
            }
            else
            {
                //Redirect User to a particular page
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                                        new RouteValueDictionary 
                                    {                                    
                                    { "controller", "Account" },
                                    { "action", "elogin" },
                                    { "redirectUrl", url.AbsolutePath}
                                    }
                );
            }
        }

    }
```

Then decorate for example Index() method with it.

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}
```

At first when you hit the Index() method then inside `OnAuthorization` method of `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` the else loop gets executed and re-directs you to a `elogin` method inside `AccountController`.  This method is similar to the Login HttpGet method. While specifying the RedirectToResult I am specifying the redirectUrl path of the current page so when you successfully validate a user inside the elogin method then with the help of redirectUrl we can come back.

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ELogin(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View("Login");
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ELogin(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                    var url =  String.Format("{0}/?g={1}", returnUrl, "HashCode");
                    return RedirectToLocal(url);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

The only difference in the HttpPost `ELogin` method is that before doing `RedirectToLocal` I append /g=HasCode.  Note: Here you can append your own logic to create a time sensitive hash.  When we get redirected to our home page then we can inspect inside our `OnAuthorization` Method if the url contains g=HashCode then don't redirect to Login Page.

This would be very basic idea on how you can approach to force users to re-sign in whenever they hit specific controllers. You will have to do additional security checks and be careful in what you are exposing via url.

Comment: But by decorating the view the ELogin method would be called before they entered any data. I need users to be able to enter their valid data first before they are redirected to confirm the data entry by signing it, then if the signing is valid, write the data to the database.

Comment: If you redirect after they submit then the data would be lost if you don't persist it before the user re-logins.

Comment: I can persist it and then rollback if they don't sign it successfully. Also thinking of using Bootstrap Modal so that I don't leave the page, but not sure how to get the values entered in the modal for use in the controller.

Comment: So if you can show the login via Modal then in the modal submit button  method you can store the value saying IsAuthenticated property in a hidden field. This hidden field could be a strongly typed property on your model and you get it in the controller.